# MySQL добавить недостающие значения в поле без удаления существующей информации

Tags: mysql, sql, update

Всем привет.
Имею таблицу с данными, структура:
**ID** / **Author** / **Name** / **Tag** / **Code** 
Встала острая необходимость продублировать данные из столбца Code в столбец Tag, но без замены уже имеющийся информации. 
Т.е. к примеру в **Tag** у меня имеются следующие данные: *Tag 1 || Tag 2 || Tag 3*, а в **Code**: *Code 1*
Я бы хотел, что бы по итогу в **Tag** получилась следующая информация: *Tag 1 || Tag 2 || Tag 3 || Code 1* 
Но к сожалению не совсем понимаю, как это выполнить.

Comment: ```update XXX set YYY = YYY + ZZZ.....```
XXX - таблица, YYY - столбец,  ZZZ - новые данные или имя столбца данные из которого нужно добавить....

не забудьте проследить чтоб разделители добавлялись, например условием что колонка не пуста ```IF(YYY='','','|| ')``` например так, хоть это и не самое лучшее решение

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков MySQL - несколько не SQL Server, и плюс поймёт не так, как ты думаешь. И простая конкатенация даст неприятный результат, если в одном из полей окажется NULL.

Comment: @Akina в тегах вижу Mysql отвечаю в его синтаксисе, про условие я не с проста дописал,.... ```IF(IFNULL()))```, и это не ответ, а направление куда копать, ответы на вопросы без попыток реализации которые сработают копипастой - я стараюсь не давать, был бы ответ - он был бы оформлен как ответ а не комментарий...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE tablename
SET tag = CONCAT_WS('||', tag, code);
```

В отличие от простого CONCAT, функция CONCAT_WS является NULL-safe.